# Flash export AVI

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I haven't ever before exported flash into movie.

When I tried to export Flash into AVI, in the final product the text disappeared. I mean the animation was still present but the text place was just blank.

What's the problem?

Comment: Does the text appear in the swf preview when you test the movie ? Try exporting to quicktime and/or png sequence and see if you have the issue. If the issue is not present it should be easy to convert/compress the .mov or image sequence to an .avi file

Comment: This might work, in GIF and SWF everything is cool. I havent tried MOV, because I don't have it, so maybe any other day I'll try exporting MOV. Thanks mate!

Comment: No worries. Regarding MOV, you should be able to select it from the Export Movie options and since Flash CS3 it has the ability to export actionscript generated graphics as well. Goodluck!

Answer (score 3):

This may be useful to someone else. Im far from being a FLASH expert, but I had problems exporting to .AVI because the text didnt apear. So I converted the text into graphic symbols (Right click) and then doubled clicked on these new symbols and broke them twice (two times ctrl+b)

Worked perfect for me!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Is the text added dynamically (via ActionScript), or added directly to the stage?

There are two ways of solving this if it is the latter:

- Embed the fonts (fiddle around with the settings for the TextField and you should find it)
- Right-click the TextField and choose "break apart" (or some command along those lines). This will convert the text to vector graphics rather than storing it as text.

Comment: this actually helped!!! I had it with a static TEXT, but i had the effect of bomb applied to it, so I removed that effect and put it without a movement...